# How can I get organic likes for a facebook post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook ad stats provide information about paid likes. However, I need to know how many organic likes did the post got for the same time period when it was server as an ad. Is there a direct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Anything organic on an ad is actually on the [hidden] page post associated it.

To get those stats you need the extended permission "read insights" on a user token associated with the page, then you can hit [page_id]_[post-id]/insights for most of the data, or any number of post engagements such as "post_consumptions_by_type".

see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights for the full list of available stats.